# SSL Error when connecting to VisualSVN

Tags: apache, ssl, tortoisesvn, router, visualsvn-server

My VisualSVN Server was working fine until we got a new router, now when I try to use TortoiseSVN to do a checkout I get the error:

```
`Unable to connect to a repository at URL` .
OPTIONS of URL: SSL handshake failed: SSL
error: unknown protocol URL
```

Any ideas on what the problem is and how to fix it?

I have already updated both the server and the client software to their latest versions.

The SSL certificate is unsigned/unverified.

Comment: Any errors on server log? What' with certificate installed on server?

Comment: @bahrep In the Event Viewer the only errors under VirtualSVN Server are password mismatches.  Am I looking in the right place?

Comment: @IanHern - you have to see at Apache log (access.log namely) - I with  bahrep suspect that the router distorts URL. Try to check repo with ordinary browser, or console command, or without router-in-the-middle

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade your VisualSVN Server to the latest version and upgrade TortoiseSVN and other svn clients, too. This should resolve the problem.

Upgrade to VisualSVN Server 4.2 is recommended for all users. Upgrade is easy and straightforward, but we strongly advise reading the [KB161: Upgrading to VisualSVN Server 4.2](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00161/) article beforehand (especially if you are upgrading from VisualSVN Server 3.9 or older versions).

You can always download the latest VisualSVN Server version from the [main download page](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/download/).

Answer (score -2):

[SSL Error when connecting to VisualSVN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12587990/ssl-error-when-connecting-to-visualsvn#new-answer?newreg=f53623104b344aa0bc4404acc154dfb1)

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjzkJ-vscT8AhVBQEEAHcWPAsgQFnoECAoQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.cloudflare.com%2Flearning%2Fssl%2Fwhat-happens-in-a-tls-handshake%2F&usg=AOvVaw0abZKHbYiLfysRwxCfbQMq

SHouldn't you find the add handshake string and code in the ssl program?

Decompile the main executable and alter only it's hand shake string?  note pad decompiler conversion or add handshake string ssl debugger application to create or an extension to find the current strings?

Go search for the branches of directories where your program is installed and shortcuts aswell, and considering you already have the servers or apps or proggiez uploaded, find the file from the website of the ssl app?  you could also rip of signatures and certificates also you could just download a signed certificate and plant it in it's destined root folder so it reads and scans as signed?

Comment: You could also add the string of the an allready signed handshake string of code?  string?

Comment: I have avoid Linux because I started hacking Red Hats Admin so they just manually uninstalled, my linux and switched my 3 cd set and put 3 cd 2s in my Red Hat set...